# Encryption required on https

Tags: iframe, encryption, asp-classic, https

We have a website running on https, we are currently loading a third party website's page within an iframe on one of the pages on our website. This third party website is again running on https and uses the referral url as our domain name (it checks if the request has originated from our website and then only loads their page). 
When we load their page we are passing across some parameters in the iframe src. Going forward we have to send few more parameters (login id etc). Do you suggest to pass these parameters using encryption or since both of the websites are running on https they are secured anyways and hence the encryption is not require?
Many thanks 
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user is allowed to see those parameters I wouldn't try to encrypt the data since you are already using SSL.

Comment: thanks, is there any possibility that the user can change the parameters?

Comment: Yes, the user has full control of what gets sent to your server. SSL only protects the data from hackers between the client and the server. The rule is to never trust incoming data/requests.

Comment: then i would use the encryption to send over the parameters as i don't want user to see other user's details. Thanks for your help

Comment: No, you need to check on the server if the current user is allowed to view other user's details.

Comment: yes even though the user is allowed to see those parameters but some users might try to alter the url so we have to stop them from doing it

Answer (score 0):

If it is in an iframe, the client will see the url passed. This means that unless you want the client to see them , you should encrypt them.

Comment: thanks, is there any possibility that the user can change the parameters?

Comment: thanks Markus, then i would use the encryption to send over the parameters as i don't want user to see other user's details. Thanks for your help

Comment: We are currently trying to implement encryption to encrypt the querystring so that the party can decrypt it...but it's becoming a nightmare to work out the public / private key pairing due to the different source (my application) and destination. Is there any generic way of implementing this? Any help will be highly appreciated?